# Identifier expected error (Java)

Tags: java, class, compiler-errors, identifier

I am new to programming and could use a helping hand.  I've created a "Person" class and a TestPerson file to test it (yes, this is an assignment.)

I am getting three errors "identifier expected" on lines 34-36 (in the setters). Clearly, this is a rookie error, but I just can't seem to figure it out.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks, in advance.

```
/******************************************************************
*     program name:      Person.java
*     author:           Nichol Albertson
*     remarks:          describes a Person object
      Date:             3/26/13
********************************************************************/
import java.text.*;

class Person {
    /**********************************************
     *  Local Variables
     ******************************************/
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private String birthday;

    /**********************************
        *   constructors - just a method
        ***********************************/

    public Person(String lastName, String firstName) {
        setLastName();
        setFirstName();
        setBirthday();
    }

    public Person(String lastName, String firstName, String birthday) {
        initialize(lastName, firstName, birthday);
    }

    /**********************************
    *   set methods  (setters)
    ***********************************/
    public void setLastName(lastName);
    public void setFirstName(firstName);
    public void setBirthday(birthday);

    /**********************************
    *   get methods  (getters)
    ***********************************/
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    /*******************************
    * other methods
    ********************************/
    public String getFirstLast() {
        System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName);
    }

    public String getLastFirst() {
        System.out.println(lastName + ", " + firstName);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Perception: Have you added `abstract` to the class definition?

Comment: Looking at the revision history for the question, yes, @Perception added `abstract` to the class.

Comment: Yep, I fat fingered that edit. Fixed now.

Comment: @Perception But OP has not declared the class as `abstract` in original code.

Comment: @VishalK - hence, why I fixed it. Take a look at the current code, the abstract keyword is removed.

Comment: your example is not minimal. Learn localizing the errors yourself minimizing your examples.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to provide a type for the parameter in each of your setter methods.  The type should match the type of the instance variable you're attempting to set.

Additionally, you should provide a method body with braces `{` and `}` for your setter methods, where you assign the parameter value to your instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

Error is showing because of following lines:

```
public void setLastName(lastName);
public void setFirstName(firstName);
public void setBirthday(birthday);
```

`Person` is neither `abstract class` nor an `interface`. It is a `concrete class` indeed.You can't just declare method within the `concrete` class . You have to provide body of methods also. This could be changed in this way:

```
public void setLastName(String lastName){ this.lastName = lastName;}
public void setFirstName(String firstName){ this.firstName = firstName;}
public void setBirthday(String birthday){ this.birthday = birthday;}
```

Moreover, following methods are defined completely wrong:

```
public String getFirstLast() {
    System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName);
}

public String getLastFirst() {
    System.out.println(lastName + ", " + firstName);
}
```

Both of above methods have return type `String` but you are returning nothing . This is also an error in your code. They should be defined as follows:

```
public String getFirstLast() {
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
}

public String getLastFirst() {
    return lastName + ", " + firstName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setLastName(lastName);
public void setFirstName(firstName);
public void setBirthday(birthday);
```

If the class is a normal class, it is neither interface nor abstract class, so a method must have the body and the other point is you need to mention the types of variables lastName, firstName and birthday.

```
   public void setLastName(String lastName)
   {
       //method's body
   }
```